# Need help transcribing handwritten characters

Tags: kanji, handwriting

Preface: I only have a very basic understanding of Japanese writing (and virtually zero actual vocabulary), and this is my first time posting here, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to translate [some handwritten text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLi68.jpg) I saw on a decorative print (linked instead of embedded because it is a massive vertical image), and I'm having trouble figuring out some of the characters (not the translation, I understand this is not the site for that).

I managed to clumsily handwrite characters 2 through 9 into Google Translate:

花九九年肖二ナ日

This translates to "Flower of 1992", which makes sense, since the print is of a flowering cherry tree branch, and could have reasonably been printed in 1992. However, I cannot even begin to decipher the first character (as the strokes blur together), and I can't seem to get the last 4 characters right. (The 3rd and 4th characters from the bottom look like they might be 王金, but if I add those to the translation, it becomes 花九九年肖二ナ日王金 - "Flower of 1999 Ninja king money")

The characters in the red square at the bottom completely baffle me. I'm guessing they're kanji, or maybe some decorative variant.

Again, I'm not asking for a translation, just the Unicode equivalent of these handwritten characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** [Here's the entire print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzqBo.jpg), in case it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 梅花九九年八月二十日　王金龍画　王金龍印
>   August 20, plum blossoms 99 - drawn by 王 金龍 - a seal/stamp of 王 金龍

This slip seems to be a part of a drawing/painting or a tag for it, because 画 *drawn by* is used instead of 書 *written by*.

It seems that he drew this painting of plum blossoms in 1999, but it is not the formal way because there is no space between 梅花 and 九九年.

王 金龍 drew this slip. The last red square figure is a seal/stamp to certify the drawer is 王金龍 himself.

Judging from the stroke order of 王, 王 金龍 is a Chinese but not a Japanese.

I am sorry to say, but his calligraphy is poor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the first character aside, I can read everything else.

花九九年八月二十日王金龍画

My rough translation: Flower August 20 1999, king gold dragon drawing

As for the red characters, they are probably seal script from the stamp of the name of the person who made it.

As far as I can tell, the first character has the tree radical on the left, but that is true of many names for flowers so not sure how much you can get from that. A native with experience in calligraphy might be able to tell you what it is.